# pgfplot references inside \only

Tags: beamer, pgfplots

If I have a pfgplot inside an `\only`, then all references are broken for some reason.
In particular, in the following MWE. The line reference shows as ?? in I have `\only` but appears normally if I comment it out.

Is this normal? Is there a way to fix it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  This is the plot

  \only<2>  % If I comment this out, the reference apears correctly
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
        [xmin=-1,xmax=1] \addplot [mark=*, samples=100] { x^2 };
        \label{line:tmp}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%

    My line is:~\ref{line:tmp}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would `visible<2>{...}` be a workaround?

Comment: Using `visible` definitely works (in the sense that the references are shown correctly), but I have to use `\only` because I don't want the figure to take space before its slide.

Comment: where you have `\label{line:tmp}`?

Comment: Right after `\addplot`

Comment: @Zarko Its inside the `tikzpicture`

Comment: i see now. it seems that label is processed to late that can be retrieved by `\ref`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bazinga :) `\label<2>{line:tmp}` does the trick!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  This is the plot

  \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
        [xmin=-1,xmax=1] \addplot [mark=*, samples=100] { x^2 };
        \label<2>{line:tmp}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%

    My line is:~\ref{line:tmp}
  \end{onlyenv}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That does solve it. Any idea why this is needed?

Comment: @Tohiko The problem seems to be that beamer tries to be too smart. Normal labels seems to be only done on the first slide of the frame to prevent the "labels multiple defined" problem. One would have to dig further into beamer to track this problem down more clearly.